# JSON over HTTP API and write The request for HTTP GET request/ response

Tags: java, json, eclipse, netbeans-8, simplejson

I am trying to write a JSON over an HTTP over a public URL(For security reason as of now I cant share the link for testing, hence assume that writing code for localhost:127.0.0.1:8083/msg)

I want to achieve this, detailed statement is described here: http://pastebin.com/42XYr23a

To achieve this I have written rough draft using Simple Json program, Kindly suggest to parse the URL and fulfill required goals.

```
java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonSimple {
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public HttpResponse http(String url, String body) {

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(body);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);

        String json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object resultObject = parser.parse(json);

            if (resultObject instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray array=(JSONArray)resultObject;
                for (Object object : array) {
                    JSONObject obj =(JSONObject)object;
                    System.out.println(obj.get("example"));
                    System.out.println(obj.get("fr"));
                }

            }else if (resultObject instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject obj =(JSONObject)resultObject;
                System.out.println(obj.get("example"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("fr"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Kindly suggest solutions

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I am newbie at Java and JSON, I am trying to learn through that problem statement, I have configured dropwizard in Netbeans 8, Now when I run the program there is dependency issues and hence compilation issues. Precise information can be observed at http://pastebin.com/BRv4FQwt

Comment: I am newbie at Java and JSON, I am trying to learn through that problem statement, I have configured dropwizard in Netbeans 8, Now when I run the program there is dependency issues and hence compilation issues. I assume that dropwizard provide all support to run JSON with Java(please corrrect me if I am wrong), Precise information about error can be observed at http://pastebin.com/BRv4FQwt . My only sole goal,I want to implement the above said problem statement in this code.